# Add field text from relationship in laravel nova in ONE form

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm new on Laravel Nova.
I'm trying to build a User form.
In this moment I have these models:
**User, UserDetail**

In User I have: email, password, username.
In UserDetail I have: Name, Lastname, Gender, Number, etc.

Now I would create **One** form for user.
Why I'm focusing on **ONE**?
Because in my User Resource fields I have:

```
HasOne::make("UserDetail", "details"),
```

But For set user detail I have 2 form:
One for User data (username, password, email) And after save the user I can set detail.

So I don't want compile 2 different form for 1 resource.

I have found this package, but seems broke:

https://github.com/yassipad/laravel-nova-nested-form/issues/66

And the fields UserDetails doens't shown.

So is there any other way for add text field from relationship and merge in same Form?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could solve this by using [Laravel's accessors and mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators).

In this example I am only going to add `gender` from `UserDetail` because I am lazy. So we start with adding a accessor for gender in our `User` model

```
public function details()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserDetail::class);
}

public function getGenderAttribute()
{
    return $this->details->gender ?? null;
}
```

This getter will get the gender from the details or null if no details exist.

Now we add a new field to our `User` resource in Nova.

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        Gravatar::make(),

        Text::make('Name')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'max:255'),

        Text::make('Email'),

        Password::make('Password'),

        Text::make('Gender')
            ->rules('required'),
    ];
}
```

Going to the create user form, it will look something like this:

[image]

Of course this will not make it save it, as it has no idea how to handle the `gender` field. For handling this we override `fillFields` method.

```
protected static function fillFields(NovaRequest $request, $model, $fields)
{
    // Get all of our user details data
    $userDetails = $request->only(['gender']);

    // Remove them from the request
    $request->request->remove('gender');

    $result = parent::fillFields($request, $model, $fields);

    // Insert them in the details object after model has been saved.
    $result[1][] = function () use ($userDetails, $model){
        $model->details()->updateOrCreate(
            [],
            $userDetails
        );
    };

    return $result;
}
```

Now we are able to see the gender field as a normal field on the user, and have no need for the `UserDetail` resource. To add more fields to be saved in the user details table, we have to add them to our only and remove them from our request. (would make sense to have that in a array)

This method also works when updating a user because we choose to use `updateOrCreate`.
[image]

A extra note about this approach is that we just introduced a n+1 query, as we are lazy loading the `details` relation when trying to get the `gender` attribute. To solve this we simply override `indexQuery` and add `details` to the query builder.

```
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    $query->with('details');
    return parent::indexQuery($request, $query);
}
```

Comment: It works! you have saved my life :D Now I have only understand what and how You have done this and how you have understand this! but It Work! thankyou so much my friend!

Comment: No problem :) So basically all the magic is in `fillFields`. That one returns an array with two elements. The first one is the model before it has been saved, but with attributes filled to it, the other element is a array of closures which will be run after it has saved.

Comment: We need the model after is has been saved because else we don't have a user id to attach our user details to.

Comment: Thank you , as soon possible(16 hours) I'll give you bounty!

Comment: No problem. Was fun hacking a solution for this

Comment: I have tested and The solutions works, but caution, because when you save other resource that is liked tho resource that you have "hacked" can throw an error on save :) but nice work! :D

Answer (score 0):

Nova 4 supports now hasOne relation inline form

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/releases.html#inline-hasone-creation